# Step by step of Integrating Docusign api with an angular app

Tags: docusignapi

I have the following use cases.

1. Authenticating the DocuSign to an Angular app.
2. List the documents
3. Get the document signed through the app

How can I do that? I couldn't find a step by step tutorial for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some "HOWTOs" at developer.docusign. You can check at https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to